# How to capture the 'X' button action in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am doing  a dirty bit chk on my form when i click on cancel button and show a confirmation msg with ok and cancel button. I would like to perform the simialr action while i click on the 'X' button as well. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to `close` event. Problem with it - your handler should return something immediately, and if you would present a question to a user it will be done asynchronously.

So you need to send `false` from that handler, preventing form from closing. Present to user a message box, and if he accepts closing - call close method yourself and not do anything during this second close.